# Partial matching a list to a list of lists

Tags: r, list

I'm still pretty new to R and I'm having a hard time properly wording this issue, so I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate.

I have a list of fixed-length lists, all with the same named members.  This is my `haystack`.
I have a list with named members, but some are missing.  This is my `needle`.

I want to return a simple TRUE/FALSE if `needle` exists in `haystack`.

**Examples:**

This should return TRUE: all of `needle`'s members match `haystack[[1]]` even though it is missing `c`

```
haystack <- list( list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), list(a = 4, b = 5, c = 6) )
needle <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
something(needle, haystack)
```

This should return FALSE: `needle`'s values match `haystack[[1]]`, but their names are different

```
haystack <- list( list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), list(a = 4, b = 5, c = 6) )
needle <- list(x = 1, y = 2)
something(needle, haystack)
```

This should return FALSE: `a = 1` and `b = 5` exist in `haystack`, but not in the same list

```
haystack <- list( list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3), list(a = 4, b = 5, c = 6) )
needle <- list(a = 1, b = 5)
something(needle, haystack)
```

---

The closest I've found so far is `lapply(haystack, match, table = needle)`, but A) it doesn't respect name matching and B) I'm not certain how to convert its results to a logical.

If there's a library that makes this easier, feel free to incorporate it into your answer.

Comment: "I have a list of fixed-length lists, all with the same named members." -- Use a data.frame: `x = do.call(rbind.data.frame, haystack)` or similar.

Comment: @Frank - At the end of what I'm working on I *do* convert the result to a data frame.  I'm still learning my way through R and I'm more familiar with manipulating lists than I am manipulating data frames. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a bit rough, but I think it can do the job. The issue we need to fix here, is to match both names and values. A very simple way to do this is to paste them together.

```
haystack2 <- lapply(haystack,function(x){
  res <- paste0(names(x),x)
  res
})
# > haystack2
# [[1]]
# [1] "a1" "b2" "c3"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "a4" "b5" "c6"

needle2 <- paste0(names(needle),needle)
# > needle2
# [1] "a1" "b2"
```

Then we can use lapply and %in%:

```
res <- any(sapply(haystack2,function(x) all(needle2 %in% x)))
# > res
# [1] TRUE
```

Wrapping in a function is easy, with an option to return the index of the haystack where the needle was found.

```
something <- function(haystack, needle, position=F){
  haystack2 <- lapply(haystack,function(x) paste0(names(x),x))
  needle2 <- paste0(names(needle),needle)
  res <- sapply(haystack2,function(x) all(needle2 %in% x))
  if(position){
    return(which(res))
  } 
  return(any(res))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Heroka's answer:

```
any(
    sapply(
        haystack,
        function(h) all( unlist( needle ) == unlist( h[names(needle)] ) )
    )
)
```

The idea is that `h[names(needle)]` returns a list of values from `h` in the order the names appear in `needle`.  We convert this into a vector, discarding the names but retaining the order.  If `all` elements of the vector match `needle` converted to a vector, this entry represents a match.

If `any` of the lists within `haystack` returned true, we return `TRUE` for the final result.

Comment: Very clever! This bypasses the need for pasting, as you eliminate the names.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I was writing the functions there have been great answers here, way better than mine. So, just to make a tiny contribution, here is what I've come up with.

```
myFunc <- function(haystack, needle, n = length(needle)){
  values <- sapply(haystack, match, table = needle)
  names <- sapply(lapply(haystack,names), match, table = names(needle))
  for(i in 1:ncol((mtx = values * names))) {
    if(sum(!is.na(mtx[,i]))==n) return(TRUE)
  }
  return(FALSE)
}
```